# How to call indirectly a C function

Tags: c++, c, scripting

Let's suppose I have the following function:

```
int func(int a, char* b, float c)
{
     return 42;
}
```

I am curios if there is a possibility to call this function without:

- explicitly calling it (`func(1, "abc", 2.4)`)
- creating a function pointer to it, and then calling it via the function pointer.

The function is written in C (or C++) and might be located either in a library (DLL on Windows) or somewhere compiled in the current application. For now let's assume there are no name mangling issues.

However, I know the following:

- the name of the function.
- the number and type of parameters as text based input (such as "`int`", "`char*`", "`float`").
- its return type

I'm open to any suggestions, but I'm somewhat afraid of some lower level assembly hacks, since I'd like this to be as portable as possible.

I'd prefer a `C` solution, and I'd like to avoid `boost::bind`...

**Edit** - some clarifications ...

The one "calling" the "function" is a scripting language's compiled library (DLL). It loads the scripting language (source file) which has "bindings" to exteral "functions" (The ones I am trying to call) and when in the scripting language it encounters "call this external function" it tries to call that external function which might be in a DLL ... or the application which actually loaded the scripting language's DLL...

Comment: These are the only options in standard, portable C.  However, there will be platform-specific approaches to accessing functions in libraries (e.g. POSIX's `dlsym`).

Comment: Is portability to architectures other that x86 and AMD64 important in your case?

Comment: @athreoz At this stage of the project I focus only on these two :)

Comment: Do you need it or is it just an intellectual exercise for students?

Comment: @Marian I do need it :)

Comment: So you can still change the C program you want to access? Then I'd recommend DBUS, it will allow calling functions from a running program even under bash: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10455

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to call functions with parameter types that are not clear at compiler time, I fear you won't come around said "lower level assembly hacks".

In cases where portability to architectures other than x86 or AMD64 isn't relevant, take a look [at this wonderful library](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/). It allows OS-unspecific ways of generating native bytecode at runtime and should be the easiest way to fulfil your wishes.

It's still beta, however I'm using it for a while now without encountering any problems.

Comment: This looks interesting, I will take a look at it to see if it can serve this purpose :)

Comment: It can sure as hell - I did something simliar with it before. :)